# Update reactive var with server Method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I have a problem with updating some values in Meteor app on client-side. I'm trying to understand how ReactiveVar works.
When I use find() method on collection on client-side the site updates immediately each time I change something. I want to achieve the same effect using ReactiveVar and server-side Method. So the code below works correctly for me:

```
// Client
Template.body.onCreated(function appBodyOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe('activities');
}

Template.body.helpers({
  getCounter() {
    return Activities.find({
       editorId: Meteor.userId(),
       'referredObject.type': 'LIST'
   }).count();
}
});
```

But when I try to achieve the same effect with server-side Method it doesn't work correctly. Code below updates variable only once. If I want to get current value I need to refresh the page.

```
// Server
Meteor.methods({'activitiesCreateCount'(userId, objectType) {
    check(userId, String);
    check(objectType, String);
    return Activities.find({
        editorId: userId,
        'referredObject.type': objectType
    }).count();
} 
});

// Client

Template.body.onCreated(function appBodyOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe('activities');
  this.activitiesAmount = new ReactiveVar(false);
}

Template.body.helpers({
  getCounter() {
    var tempInstance = Template.instance();
    Meteor.call('activitiesCreateCount', Meteor.userId(), 'TODO', function(err, response) {
      tempInstance.activitiesAmount.set(response);
    });
    return Template.instance().activitiesAmount.get();
}
});
```

How I can improve my code if I want always have a current value of the variable (like in the first client-side only example)?

Comment: It works as it's supposed to work. If you have a working solution why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Assume that I have a complex and time consuming task. If one user change something it should trigger this complex task and the result should be updated on another specific user screen. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do this complex task on client-side so I'm trying to find another solutions.

Comment: If this imaginary "complex and time-consuming task" changes some value in some doc in some collection just subscribe to it and you have it always up to date. To reduce the amount of data sent to client use `fields`.

Comment: If you want to use method anyway you should define conditions to it being rerun. If you put it in the helper, also put some reactive data source into that helper, so that when this reactive data source changes, helper reruns.

Answer (score -2):

Try to move `Meteor.call`to `Template.body.onCreated`
Something like this

```
  // Server
  Meteor.methods({'activitiesCreateCount'(userId, objectType) {
      check(userId, String);
      check(objectType, String);
      return Activities.find({
          editorId: userId,
          'referredObject.type': objectType
      }).count();
  } 
  });

  // Client

  Template.body.onCreated(function appBodyOnCreated() {        
    self = this;
    this.activitiesAmount = new ReactiveVar(false);
    Meteor.call('activitiesCreateCount', Meteor.userId(), 'TODO', function(err, response) {
      self.activitiesAmount.set(response);
    });
  }

  Template.body.helpers({
    getCounter() {
      return Template.instance().activitiesAmount.get();
  }
  });
```

Comment: Which as well runs only once.